# Kernel config diffs - better way to maintain

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, patch

I maintain one Linux distro (LEAF) with multiple kernel targets, so it needs to have multiple kernel configs (one reference config + usual patch files for other targets). But this adds headache on kernel update - some new options at patch place break patch, so I should take a lot of time to re-create config.

Is there a solution to store just different variables instead of context diffs (and, of course, patch config with these variables)? Or there's no such tool and I should write parser by myself?

Comment: maybe storing them in a git tree ?

Comment: They already are in git tree. Question is how to sync config changes for multiple archs (for ex., enabling/disabling some drivers) with minimal spent time.

Comment: If you're finding that diffs don't meet your needs, the best option may be to write your own pre-build system that assembles a final kernel configuration from a set of different options. You can then start with a base set of common options and then merge with some platform-specific additions/removals to arrival at the final configuration. The [Debian kernel handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/) may also provide some useful information to see how they handle such issues.

Comment: Maintaining this on kernel update will be a much bigger headache than maintaining config + diffs...